# Can I decide the authenticate service to response AccountManager for the same account type?

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am developing an account SDK based on AccountManager for multiple android apps. We are going to integrate SDK in every app, that can share account with each other like Google apps. But we meet a problem:

*If there are more than one app with same account type in AccountManager, which app would be called when managing my account?*

I have tried some demo codes and found out that *the first app installed on device may be preferred to response AccountManager*. That means old SDK would be called until the firs one is upgraded or deleted even though the other apps are upgraded.

**What is the rule when Account Manager calling service to respond? Is it possible to custom the preferred response service?**

Comment: Those multiple android apps? Will they all be authored by the same company using the same key? or authored by different third party developers using different keys?

Comment: I don't think this is related to keys for signature while different keys may be used. Android AccountManager manages accounts based on account type rather than developers, right?

Comment: You're correct, but the reason I was asking was because of a possible workaround I was thinking about.

Comment: So... Do you have any idea or experience to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you answer my initial questions? There is no need to vet me. If I can't find a workaround to your problem, I'll just tell you straight out.

Comment: I already answered u that different keys would be used..

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't get that from your previous answer. I was only asking because if the same developer key could have been used, and the same shared user id could have been shared across applications, then all those apps could have shared the same copy of your sdk.

Comment: That case described in your answer would be great that all apps shared the same copy of my sdk. But different copy of sdk might be considered while upgrades of different apps are up to users.

Comment: Again, it depends if your sdk is to be used for different apps by different teams within the same company, or if it's going to be a public sdk to be used by several third party developers. When updating an app with a shared id signed by the same developer certificate, the user of the phone doesn't get to decide what part of the app gets updated. And Google Play will update the same library for all the apps using it in a single download (assuming the different dependent apps can all be signed by the same developer certificate and be using the same shared id).

Comment: To be confirmed, you are talking a jar file under lib/ when you are talking about library, right? Or you are implying that the sdk should be in a form of apk?